# Draw a pair of NON isomorphic graphs with same no. of vertices, same degree sequence and same cycle lengths.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I'm very new to graph theory and I've been struggling with this question because while I can come up with an example with the same degree sequence, I'm not sure how it's possible with the same cycle lengths as well.

Comment: Try doing it with no cycles at all: that's the easiest way for the cycle lengths to be the same.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for replying! I suppose I could try with acyclic graphs but I run into the same issue because I'm not sure what exactly should I do to make the graphs non isomorphic. I know adjacency is a property I could play around with but I'm still really stuck.

Comment: One way to distinguish graphs with the same degree sequence is to say things like "In graph $G$, the two vertices with degree $5$ are adjacent. Graph $H$ also has two vertices with degree $5$, but they're not adjacent." Can you use that to come up with an example?

Comment: Consider trees with degree sequence $3,2,\dots,2,1,1,1$.

Comment: @bof thank you for replying! But how would it be non isomorphic?

Comment: Draw two trees, each with degree sequence $3,2,2,2,1,1,1$, so that onlone has diameter $4$ and the other has diameter $5$.